# getting duplicate values in a Set of tuples

Tags: java, collections, set

I am trying to create a Set in java for a tuple of integers.

For example:

```
class Tuple
{
    int first;
    int second;
    public Tuple(int i, int j)
    {
        this.first=i;
        this.second=j;
    }
}
```

And then trying to populate a set like this:

```
Set pairs = new HashSet<Tuple>();
pairs.add(new Tuple(1,2));
pairs.add(new Tuple(1,2));
pairs.add(new Tuple(1,2));
```

For a number of tuple objects. But still I am getting duplicates by:

```
System.out.println("Size: " + pairs.size());
for (Tuple t : (HashSet<Tuple>) pairs) {
    System.out.println(t.toString());
}
```

Can anyone help to get rid of duplicates?

Comment: How do you think duplicates are discovered?

Answer (score 7):

Override the `hashCode()` and `equals()` methods.

When you want to say two objects are equal, their hashCodes need to be implemented in a way that it will return the same value and `equals()` will return true. When we try to insert an object into a hash data structure, it first calls `hashCode()` on that object and then `equals()`method with the object from the collection having same hash code as that of this object.

I assume you want only one `Tuple` object in you `HashSet`. Change your class as follows:

```
public class Tuple {
    int first;
    int second;
    public Tuple(int i, int j){
        this.first=i;
        this.second=j;
    }
    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result + first;
        result = prime * result + second;
        return result;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        Tuple other = (Tuple) obj;
        if (first != other.first)
            return false;
        if (second != other.second)
            return false;
        return true;
    }     
}
```

Answer (score 4):

`Tuple` must implement `hashCode` and `equals` for it to work in a `HashSet`.